# Asp.Net Grid View. Move last column onto new row and span other columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is it possible in a Grid View control to move the last column onto a new row and have that new row span the previous columns?

Something like:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
Col6
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
Col6
```

Comment: That breaks the concept of row-based data.

Comment: it's better to use Datalist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code to get the format you're asking for. Look at the last `<asp:TemplateField>` which has required code to move your last column into a new row.

[image]

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="false"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0"
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Col1" HeaderText="Col 1" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Col2" HeaderText="Col 2" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Col3" HeaderText="Col 3" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Col4" HeaderText="Col 4" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Col5" HeaderText="Col 5" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="100%">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Col6") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <itemstyle width="100%" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

The datasource object I used for gridview binding

```
public class GridViewColumns
{
    public String Col1 { get; set; }
    public String Col2 { get; set; }
    public String Col3 { get; set; }
    public String Col4 { get; set; }
    public String Col5 { get; set; }
    public String Col6 { get; set; }
}
```

And your `PageLoad`

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
        var datasource = new List<GridViewColumns>() {
        new GridViewColumns { 
            Col1 = "Col 1",
            Col2 = "Col 3",
            Col3 = "Col 3",
            Col4 = "Col 4",
            Col5 = "Col 5",
            Col6 = "Col 6"
        },
        new GridViewColumns { 
            Col1 = "Col 1",
            Col2 = "Col 3",
            Col3 = "Col 3",
            Col4 = "Col 4",
            Col5 = "Col 5",
            Col6 = "Col 6"
        }
      };

      GridView1.DataSource = datasource;
      GridView1.DataBind();
}
```